# generate increment number in select statement using SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table named table1 in SQL server as follows:

```
colA
-------
A123
Z123
C123
B123
```

now I want to use one SQL statement to get the result as follows:

```
ID colA
--------
1  A123
2  Z123
3  C123
4  B123
```

The order of colA is as the order of row in the table. Do not need to sort it.

how to do that??
Thanks a lot

Comment: The order rows are returned from a table in SQL are random unless you use an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 23):

Here's what I always do when I need an incrementing ID *without sorting the data* (because my other row or rows are neither alphabetical nor chronological). Also, I despise using temp tables unless they are absolutely necessary.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(
    ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
) as ID, colA
FROM table1
```

Comment: You mean you think GETDATE() is re-evaluated with every row? Even if that were the case, what if the query returned 1000 rows in 20 ms? Would you consider the row numbers reliable (as in "matching the order in which they were returned according to GETDATE()"), especially given the fact that GETDATE returns a `datetime` whose granularity is 3 ms?

Comment: Well, you guys are right. I'm rather new at this, as you might have figured out. I modified my answer using the input of @paul-white

Comment: There are many examples using 'OVER' but this is the first one I found suggesting '(SELECT NULL)'.
It's just what I was looking for.
Two thumbs good, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Example using ROW_NUMBER

```
             SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (ORDER BY colA)  AS Row, 
                colA
                FROM table1
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this using a `Table variable with an Identity column`.

> The order of colA is as the order of row in the table. Do not need to
>   sort it.

**[Fiddle demo:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee91b/1)**

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), colA varchar(50))

--No ordering done and the same results won't be guaranteed
insert into @t select colA from Table1

select id, colA from @T
```

results:

```
| ID | COLA |
|----|------|
|  1 | A123 |
|  2 | Z123 |
|  3 | C123 |
|  4 | B123 |
```

Comment: Accepting that the Id for a colA value might be different each time this SQL is run.

Comment: @ForkandBeard: Yes, OP says, he does not need to order. If colA is has a clustered index, this will give same results (unless rows are deleted).

Comment: I don't think a clustered index affects the order results are returned just how they're stored.

Comment: @ForkandBeard, In sql server, when you create a key column it adds a `clustered index` automatically which `decides the physical order` of the rows in that table and that is the reason why you can have only one clustered index per table.

Comment: Yes they are stored in that order but the select can be random unless you specify an ORDER BY.

Comment: @ForkandBeard: As far as I know, if you have a clustered index and if you don't order it will be the physical order.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't guarantee that a `SELECT` on a table with a clustered index returns the results in clustered index key order. Even if the plan shows a CI scan [Transaction Isolation level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/11/09/when-can-allocation-order-scans-be-used.aspx), [SQL Server Edition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475(v=sql.105).aspx) and Degree of Parallelism all might mean the results aren't in that order.

Comment: I think that's intuitively the case, from experience, but it's just not a guarantee.

Comment: Okay guys. I accept that. Thank you both! Is it possible to replicate this scenario?

Comment: ...given that you're dealing with transaction level and parallelism, not easily (if at all).  Side note - given that data, I'd assume it'd be returned in _alphabetical_ order, not the "initial" order the OP presents.

Answer (score 2):

Generating Row number when dynamic order conditions are present

```
select TotalCount = COUNT(U.UnitID) OVER() ,

ROW_NUMBER() over(
    order by 
     (CASE @OrderBy WHEN '1' THEN m.Title  END) ASC ,
     (CASE @OrderBy WHEN '2' THEN m.Title  END) DESC,
     (CASE @OrderBy WHEN '3' THEN Stock.Stock  END) DESC,
     (CASE @OrderBy WHEN '4' THEN Stock.Stock   END) DESC

) as RowNumber,

M.Title,U.ColorCode,U.ColorName,U.UnitID, ISNULL(Stock.Stock,0) as Stock

 from tblBuyOnlineMaster M

    inner join BuyOnlineProductUnitIn U on U.BuyOnlineID=M.BuyOnlineID 

    left join 
            ( select IT.BuyOnlineID,IT.UnitID,ISNULL(sum(IT.UnitIn),0)-ISNULL(sum(IT.UnitOut),0) as Stock 
                from [dbo].[BuyOnlineItemTransaction] IT 
                group by IT.BuyOnlineID,IT.UnitID
             ) as Stock

        on U.UnitID=Stock.UnitID


order by 
 (CASE @OrderBy WHEN '1' THEN m.Title  END) ASC ,
 (CASE @OrderBy WHEN '2' THEN m.Title  END) DESC,
 (CASE @OrderBy WHEN '3' THEN Stock.Stock  END) DESC,
 (CASE @OrderBy WHEN '4' THEN Stock.Stock   END) DESC


offset  @offsetCount rows fetch next 6 rows only
```